# Only select book with multiple authors and display book title, publisher and author name

Tags: mysql

I need to produce the following:

```
Title         Publisher Name   Author Last  Author First
========================================================
Treasure      Tauntan Press     Smith       John
Treasure      Tauntan Press     Jones       Andrew
```

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
Book_Title as 'Title',
Publisher_Name,
Author_Last,
Author_First
FROM BOOK
JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)
JOIN WROTE USING (Book_Code)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num);

select BOOK.* 
FROM BOOK
JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)
JOIN WROTE USING (Book_Code)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num)
inner join (
    SELECT 
    Book_Title as Title,
    Publisher_Name
    FROM BOOK
    JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)
    JOIN WROTE USING (Book_Code)
    JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num)
    group by  Book_Title, Publisher_Name
    having count(distinct concat(Author_Last,Author_First)) = 2
) t on t.Title = BOOK.Book_Title 
        and t.Publisher_Name = PUBLISHER.Publisher_Name
```

And it produces the following:

```
Code      Book Title  Book Type   Book Paperback  Publisher Code
=================================================================
 1234    Treasure      Art       FALSE            AAA
 1234    Treasure      Art       FALSE            AAA
```

What needs to be added/amended to produce the correct output?  I appreciate the support I have received thus far, it's been a steep learning curve.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

you could use having count(distinct concat(LastName,FirstName)) = 2 
grouping by  Title and Publisher

```
    SELECT 
    Book_Title as 'Title',
    Publisher_Name
    FROM BOOK
    JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)
    JOIN WROTE USING (Book_Code)
    JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num)
    group by  Boo, k_Title, Publisher_Name
    having count(distinct concat(LastName,FirstName)) = 2
```

and for obtain all the values  in book related  to these book titles

```
select BOOK.* 
FROM BOOK
JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)
JOIN WROTE USING (Book_Code)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num)
inner join (
    SELECT 
    Book_Title as Title,
    Publisher_Name
    FROM BOOK
    JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)
    JOIN WROTE USING (Book_Code)
    JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num)
    group by  Boo, k_Title, Publisher_Name
    having count(distinct concat(LastName,FirstName)) = 2
) t on t.Title = BOOK.Book_Title 
        and t.Publisher_Name = PUBLISHER.Publisher_Name
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge.  Unfortunately it;s not what I need to produce.  This lists the Title and Publisher once........ What I actually need is:                                                                    
                                                                                                                            Title1   Publisher1   authorlname1   authorfname1
Title1   Publisher1   authorlname2   authorfname2

Comment: @ppines  .. answer  updated  with the final result  too..(Given the query for books with two authors it did not seem difficult to get the final result .). anyway

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge.   This updated code is producing syntax errors.  I'll  just have to do more research.  I appreciate your effort.

Comment: show me the exact error mesage.. anyway  .. asnwer  updated .. adding the tables  involved in query

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge. The error related to LastName,FirstName... which I have amended to Author_Last, Author_First.  However, the table it produces is not showing the right columns for some reason.    This is what it is supposed to produce:

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge. The error related to LastName,FirstName... which I have amended to Author_Last, Author_First.  However, the table it produces is not showing the right columns for some reason.                                                                                           This is what it is supposed to produce: 

Title       Publisher Name   Author Last  Author First
==============================================
Treasure   Tauntan Press     Smith       John
Treasure   Tauntan Press     Jones       Andrew 

* sorry I can’t get the comments to show a table structure*

Comment: But it’s producing:

Book Code   Book Title  Book Type   Book Paperback  Publisher Code
============================================================= 
1234        aaaaaa     bbbbbb     FALSE          ABC

I’m really confused now as it is displaying primary key data instead of using the primary key to join the tables to produce the table I need.  How can we fix this?  Really appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: Update  your question and add the tables struct in the question